# why is "go version -m" missing hashes

Tags: go, go-modules

I have two go compiled binaries.

One, my simple experiment, has `go version -m` report module names, versions and `h1:` hashes (from `go.sum`). This was true across versions of go tested from 1.16 through 1.19.

The second, from an external provider, reports only module names and versions, no hashes. This was compiled with go1.18.6 (I did not compile it, but have access to source).

Why would a compiled binary be missing the hashes from `go.sum`?

Comment: Do you have access to the Makefile? May be they set `runtime.modinfo` symbol using `-X` linker flag?

Comment: I do have access to the makefile; `runtime.modinfo` is not set. However, using that as the beginning of a trail, I eventually found [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46400) which appears to be mine. So thank you for giving me something to start with.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be an issue of the interaction between `go build -mod=vendor` and go module cache (default `${GOPATH}/pkg/mod` or as set via `GOMODCACHE`). In short, when `go build` inserts the module information into the compiled binary, it fetches the hashes *not* from `go.sum`, but rather from the module cache.

- When using non-vendored packages (i.e. **not** `-mod=vendor`), by definition it downloads or updates everything in the package cache and takes the hashes from there.
- When using vendored packages (i.e. `-mod=vendor`), it uses everything in `vendor/`, but *still* looks in the package cache for hashes, even though it may not have the modules there, and doesn't really need them (that *is* the point of vendoring).

The above is true even though `go build` uses the hashes `go.sum` to compare against what it is building in.

Thanks to [commenter Pat Ula above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74223301/why-is-go-version-m-missing-hashes?noredirect=1#comment131048926_74223301), who gave something to start the long thread of finding the answer.

The actual issue can be found [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46400)